# Wso2 Identity server 5.3.0 and fido token

Tags: wso2, fido-u2f, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.3.

I integrated it with U2F.

When I use it in authentication, it give me a blank page (https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/fido-auth.jsp)
but when I use it with previous version its work well!

What is the problem between the last version and Fido token ?

And why the fido token works just with (google-chrome) not (Firefox) ?

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part of your question, I assume you're not supposed to be "air-dropped" straight into that page, rather naturally be directed to it after providing username & password. Also, try to check the inner system log of wso2, you shall find it under 'monitor' tab.

For the second part of your question please refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121484/fido-u2f-tokens-web-browsers-compatibilty)

tl;dr:
Chrome supports FIDO by default starting from its 40th version, while Mozila is on its way to support it and in the mean time you can use [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/u2f-support-add-on/)