# Re-enable FIDO U2F in Chromium 98 +

Tags: chromium, fido-u2f

In recent versions of Chromium (98+), my Yubikey is broken / no longer working to authenticate / register with websites using the FIDO2 U2F standard.

For example this demo site: https://u2f.cloudentify.com/u2fdemo/

Simply nothing happens and this is written to the console:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('chrome-extension://kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

How can I get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the way U2F was implemented in Chromium was a bit of a hack and has been [deprecated since Chrome 95](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deps-rems-95/#deprecate-u2f-api-cryptotoken).  Here is the [Yubikey page](https://www.yubico.com/blog/google-chrome-u2f-api-decommission-what-the-change-means-for-your-users-and-how-to-prepare/).  It should have been a smooth transition to WebAuthn, but this is not true for all websites.

How to re-enable U2F API:

1. Go to this url: `chrome://flags/#u2f-security-key-api`
2. Locate "Enable the U2F Security Key API"
   [image: Enable the U2F Security Key API]
3. Change the dropdown from "Default" to "Enabled".
4. Restart the browser.

Comment: It will eventually be removed though, so it might be worth it reaching out to the website to have them migrate to webauthn.

Comment: On Chromium Linux, even Webauthn doesn't work without this change... it seems the yubikey is not recognized, doesn't blink, etc.  In future versions of Chromium (103 or 106?) the Yubikey _should_ start working again via Webauthn according to what I have found online.  If you have more info, please share.

Comment: Just noting for everyone that as of Chrome 104, the [U2F API has been completely removed](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deps-rems-104/).